# Web Essential source map: Bundling Sources url is not using full path

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, web-essentials

I used web essential in my application to generate source map for custom JQuery script files.

MyBundle.min.js.map is as follows:

```
{
"version":3,
"file":"MyBundle.min.js",
"lineCount":1,
"mappings":"AAMAA,SAASA,IAAI,CAAA,CAAG,EANhBC,CAAC,CAACC,QAAD,CAAUC,MAAM,CAAC,QAAS,CAAA,CAAG,CAC1BF,CAAC,CAAC,cAAD,CAAgBG,MAAM,CAAC,QAAS,CAAA,CAAG,CAChCH,CAAC,CAAC,IAAD,CAAMI,IAAI,CAAC,CAAE,eAAe,CAAE,MAAnB,CAAD,CADqB,CAAb,CADG,CAAb,CAIf,CCSFJ,CAAC,CAACC,QAAD,CAAUC,MAAM,CAAC,QAAS,CAAA,CAAG,CAC1BF,CAAC,CAAC,cAAD,CAAgBG,MAAM,CAAC,QAAS,CAAA,CAAG,CAChCH,CAAC,CAAC,IAAD,CAAMI,IAAI,CAAC,CAAE,aAAa,CAAE,MAAjB,CAAD,CADqB,CAAb,CADG,CAAb,CAIf",
"sources":["/Scripts/Test.js","/Scripts/another.js"],
"names":["Test","$","document","ready","click","css"]
}
```

sources is not generating using full path. When I deploy code to different environment, application name is not same for all the environments.

```
Prod url: http://Appprod/ccc
QA url: http://Appqa/ccc
```

When I try to add source map (chrome) in deployed sites, scripts are coming as empty.

In local, it is working as expected.

Can anyone please help me to set the fullpath for the sources?

Note: I generated the bundle JQuery scripts using the url: http://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2013/03/18/Combining-JavaScript-bundling-minification-cache-busting-and-easier-debugging